# Chef knife-spork Git plugin not committing or pushing

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife, configuration-management, spork

I'm having issues getting the Git plugin for knife-spork to commit and push to it's repo.

Here's the output from `knife spork info`:

```
{"version_change_threshold"=>2,
"preserve_constraint_operators"=>true, 
"always_promote_remote"=>true, 
"skip_berkshelf"=>false, 
"role_match_file_name"=>true, 
"role_safe_delete"=>true, 
"json_options"=>{"indent"=>"  "}, 
"plugins"=>{
  "git"=>{
    "auto_push"=>true, 
    "remote"=>"origin", 
    "branch"=>"master" 
  }
}}

[...]
KnifeSpork::Plugins::Git: enabled
[...]
```

When I do a `knife spork bump COOKBOOK minor`:

```
Git: Pulling latest changes from /path/to/chef-repo/cookbooks/COOKBOOK
Pulling latest changes from git submodules (if any)
Successfully bumped base to v0.2.0!
Git add'ing /path/to/chef-repo/cookbooks/COOKBOOK/metadata.rb
```

Which only adds it ... Then I do `knife spork upload COOKBOOK`:

```
Git: Pulling latest changes from /path/to/chef-repo/cookbooks/COOKBOOK
Pulling latest changes from git submodules (if any)
Freezing COOKBOOK at 0.2.0...
Successfully uploaded COOKBOOK@0.2.0!
```

Which uploads the cookbook to the chef server, but doesn't commit to the repo or try pushing ... And there's no errors output :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay Yep I had misunderstood the flow ...

So You have to create your environments first:

```
knife spork environment create production
knife spork environment create development
```

Then once the cookbook is ready for an environment, you `promote` it

```
knife spork promote development COOKBOOK
```

And it then commits and pushes it

Comment: If you're just starting out with Chef, I would highly recommend looking at the Policy workflow instead of Spork. It's very similar but has some purpose-built workflow tooling.